# Why is my answer to this security exam prep question incorrect?

Tags: certification, theory

I'm studying for a security exam and am confused by one of the chapter review questions in the book I'm using.  It reads:

> When scanning a network via a hardline connection to a wired-switch
>   NIC in promiscuous mode, what would be the extent of network traffic
>   you would expect to see?
>
> A. Entire network.
>     B. VLAN you are attached to.
>     C. All nodes attached to the same port.
>   D. None

My chosen answer was **D**. According to the book, the correct answer is **C** with the following explanation:

> Because each switchport is its own collision domain, only nodes that reside on the same switchport will be seen during a scan.

While I agree that each port on a switch becomes its own separate collision domain (in the case of half-duplex connectivity), I don't see how multiple nodes can be attached to "the same port".  Wouldn't this be physically unlikely (if not impossible)?

I checked with the book publisher but didn't see any additional clarification or errata notes.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A switch does not map just one MAC address per port. Multiple nodes can connect to a second hub or switch, which will be connected to the first switch on a single port.

An eavesdropper listening on that port can potentially listen to the network traffic of all hosts connected to the second network device whose destination is a host on the first switch.

Comment: and trunk lines, and, and ...

Comment: D'oh. Makes sense.  I was thinking of "attached" in the physical sense of the word.  Thanks.